# IntelliJ IDEA 13 problems running plain Scala application

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have an absolutely basic Scala project made in IDEA. The folder structure is just `.idea`, `src` and `projectName.iml`. Inside `src` I have only one file named `Main.scala`. The contents of that file are:

```
object Main extends App
{
    println("Hello, World")
}
```

I am trying to simply run this code from inside IDEA. In Eclipse/Java, this would be accomplished simply by right-clicking the main class file and clicking on "Run As... Java Application".

Apparently, IDEA doesn't automatically recognise Main.scala as executable, so the context menu does not contain such an option. There is only `Run Scala Console`, which is absolutely not what I need, and doesn't even seem to work properly (it says `type :help to see more`, but typing it only highlights the text as an error). Looking around in Google, I found that you can do the following:

- go to the main program context menu called `Run`, choose `Edit Configurations`
- click the `+` button to add a new configuration, select `Application` as base
- select the main class of the run configuration, input any other stuff if you need it, then save the configuration

And this is where the problem lies. I can not select the main class. When I click the browse button next to the `Main class:` input field, choose the `Project` tab, browse to `src/Main` and click `OK`, an alert window pops up with the text `Main is not acceptable`.

That error message gives me absolutely no information as to WHY it is not acceptable, which is particularly annoying because the same project structure would work with Java projects.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

P.S. IDEA version 13.1.3, scala version 2.11.1.

Comment: your src directory is [marked as source directory](http://take.ms/wG31D), right? (screenshot is for java, but should be the same for scala). Is that file even recognized as scala source?

Comment: @om-nom-nom yes, it's marked so automatically when you create a new project. Obviously the code is recognised as scala code, auto-complete and code analysis works correctly.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem by creating new project via IDEA wizard and [everything works fine](http://take.ms/plCH3). The only additional action I've made besides clicking next/next/finish was choosing proper scala distribution (in case of OSX it was `/usr/local/opt/scala/idea`). I'm on IDEA 13.1.2, scala plugin 0.35.683

Comment: Does it work if instead of extending `App` you define an actual `def main(args: Array[String])` function?

Comment: My scala plugin version is 0.38.437. Where am I supposed to choose the `proper scala distribution`? I'm on Windows, Scala is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\scala` and all my settings are in these screenshots: http://prntscr.com/3tr2j8, http://prntscr.com/3tr2ko, http://prntscr.com/3tr2ls, http://prntscr.com/3tr2mv, http://prntscr.com/3tr2np, http://prntscr.com/3tr2p6

Comment: @vptheron - no, it doesn't change anything... Weird.

Comment: I didn't had scala bundle as a global library, [so I had to choose it there](http://take.ms/T8gFS). Shouldn't be a root of the problem, because looks like you already have present and configured scala. Weird.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked Help... About, and it says that it's using JRE1.7.0_40, even though my JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to `C:\Program Files\jdk1.8.0` and PATH contains `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin`. `java -version` says `"1.8.0_05"`... Maybe that somehow influences it, since I've set compiler level to 1.8.0?
Edit: w8, but if I edit the JDK path in project settings, it shows it's using 1.8.0 correctly...

Comment: The most stupid thing is that Scala IDE (the one based on Eclipse) does this all out of the box without any trouble, almost no configuration needed. But here I can't even run 3 lines of code. Ridiculous!

Comment: I have the same problem. The only thing I can do is "Run Scala Console"